# Is it possible to retrieve the _whole_ friendlist of a user using the iOS Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am reading through the docs and other questions on Stackoverflow. Am I getting this right that it is actually impossible to retrieve **the whole friendlist** of the user? The permissions `user_friends` only refers to friends that [have previously logged](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends?locale=de_DE) into the same app with Facebook.

I am wondering if I just oversee the solution or if it is indeed impossible to get access to a user's friends because there is no API that would allow to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since graph API v2.0, this is no longer possible:

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends#readperms

> This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

Comment: ok, that's was I was afraid of. thanks for the confirmation and the links to the docs though, that'll help explain it to the customer ;)

Comment: You might have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends/ but they both do probably not support your original use case.

Comment: I already checked out the `invitable_friends` API, this would do it for me but unfortunately this one is **only available if your FB app also available on _canvas_**. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As Tobi says, in V2.0 this is no longer possible.

But, if you want to get only name and profile picture, then its possible!
Check [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends)

Note that The `id` that returns this API call isn't unique, it may change for every request for same user, so you can't use that field to identify user, you can use it ONLY for tagging.

Comment: Taggable_friends are only to tag people and will not get approved for anything else